# Why does my entry in the "Your Virtual Hosts" submenu not contain the full name of the host?

Tags: wampserver

I have set up a new virtual host on WAMP Server version 3.0.6 which contains a dot in the name (specifically bowla300.local)

My vhosts.conf file is configured to call it bowla300.local, as is also my hosts file. When I restart WAMP the localhost page shows this name correctly in both the Your Projects and Your Virtual Hosts columns and the links work as expected. So far so good... But on the Your Virtual Hosts menu from the main WAMP server the server name appears only as bowla300 without the .local at the end and the link does not work. I don't know what I need to change to correct this. It is possible that I initially set the site name up incorrectly without the ".local" but having subsequently revisited vhosts.conf the name is now definitely correct and the fact it appears correct on the localhost page also suggests it is valid. Any ideas why the menu entry may not be including the ".local"?

I attach my vshosts entries as below (which I admit I did hand edit as I have only just noticed the option on the local host page to create a virtual host that way):-

```
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
        <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
                Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName bowla300.local
        DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/bowla300.local"
        <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/bowla300.local/">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You probably forgot to restart the `dmscache` service. `net stop dnscache` then `net start dnscache`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I am only an occasional dabbler in WAMP and web technologies in general (its not really one of my core competencies) and although I would like to learn more, I am still at the stage where I forget basic things from time to time. I guess the point is that the DNS service sits below the WAMP stack and therefore stopping that on its own isn't good enough, but I didn't need to go as far as a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself after a clean reboot. Restarting WAMP was not sufficient but restarting the operating system fixed it.